# How to highlight a span of text in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I’m building a mock writing test app with flutter. I need to display the writing prompt in the top of the screen while the user can write the essay below. 
I’d like to allow the user to select  the key words in the prompt and highlight them to help them stay focused on the topic while writing. How can it be achieved?

Comment: `RichText` is used for selecting part of text. It'll be better if you paste code - what did you already try

Answer (score 0):

simply do this

```
String title ="<mark>"+_SelectedWordToSearch+"<mark>"
enter code here
```